# Why I obtain this error message when I try to move the configuration class as an inner class of the test class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have the following problem with an exercise related to the use of **JUnit** test in Spring.

So I have the following **configuration class** named `TestInfrastructureConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@Import({
    TestInfrastructureDevConfig.class,
    TestInfrastructureProductionConfig.class,
    RewardsConfig.class })
public class TestInfrastructureConfig {

    public LoggingBeanPostProcessor loggingBean(){
        return new LoggingBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

This class configure the **test environment**-

Now in an exercise say that:

> In Spring when no configuration class or configurationXML file is
>   specified, `@ContextConfiguration` will look for an inner class marked
>   with `@Configuration` (If none is found it will also look for an XML
>   file name of `<Classname>`-context.xml). Since the
>   `TestInfrastructureConfig` class is so small anyway, copy the entire
>   class definition, including annotations, to an inner class withing the
>   test class. Then remove the configuration class reference from the
>   `@ContextConfiguration` annotation (no property in the brackets). This
>   is an example of convention over configuration.

So I have totally commentd the code of the `TestInfrastructureConfig` class that become:

```
//package rewards;
//
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
//
//import config.RewardsConfig;
//
//@Configuration
//@Import({
//  TestInfrastructureDevConfig.class,
//  TestInfrastructureProductionConfig.class,
//  RewardsConfig.class })
//public class TestInfrastructureConfig {
//
//  public LoggingBeanPostProcessor loggingBean(){
//      return new LoggingBeanPostProcessor();
//  }
//}
```

Then in the `RewardNetworkTests` I change:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestInfrastructureConfig.class)
```

into:

```
@ContextConfiguration()
```

and I add the code of the commented `TestInfrastructureConfig` into the `RewardNetworkTests` class as an inner class, something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestInfrastructureConfig.class)
@ContextConfiguration()
//@ActiveProfiles("jdbc")
//@ActiveProfiles({ "jdbc", "jdbc-dev" })
@ActiveProfiles({ "jdbc", "jdbc-production" })
public class RewardNetworkTests {


    /**
     * The object being tested.
     */
    @Autowired
    private RewardNetwork rewardNetwork;

    @Test
    public void testRewardForDining() {
        // create a new dining of 100.00 charged to credit card
        // '1234123412341234' by merchant '123457890' as test input
        Dining dining = Dining.createDining("100.00", "1234123412341234",
                "1234567890");

        // call the 'rewardNetwork' to test its rewardAccountFor(Dining) method
        RewardConfirmation confirmation = rewardNetwork
                .rewardAccountFor(dining);

        // assert the expected reward confirmation results
        assertNotNull(confirmation);
        assertNotNull(confirmation.getConfirmationNumber());

        // assert an account contribution was made
        AccountContribution contribution = confirmation
                .getAccountContribution();
        assertNotNull(contribution);

        // the contribution account number should be '123456789'
        assertEquals("123456789", contribution.getAccountNumber());

        // the total contribution amount should be 8.00 (8% of 100.00)
        assertEquals(MonetaryAmount.valueOf("8.00"), contribution.getAmount());

        // the total contribution amount should have been split into 2
        // distributions
        assertEquals(2, contribution.getDistributions().size());

        // each distribution should be 4.00 (as both have a 50% allocation)
        assertEquals(MonetaryAmount.valueOf("4.00"), contribution
                .getDistribution("Annabelle").getAmount());
        assertEquals(MonetaryAmount.valueOf("4.00"), contribution
                .getDistribution("Corgan").getAmount());
    }   

    @Configuration
    @Import({
        TestInfrastructureDevConfig.class,
        TestInfrastructureProductionConfig.class,
        RewardsConfig.class })
    public class TestInfrastructureConfig {

        public LoggingBeanPostProcessor loggingBean(){
            return new LoggingBeanPostProcessor();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to run the test I obtain the red bar, the test is not passed, and the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader was able to detect defaults, and no ApplicationContextInitializers were declared for context configuration [ContextConfigurationAttributes@52d455b8 declaringClass = 'rewards.RewardNetworkTests', locations = '{}', classes = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoader']
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.processContextConfiguration(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:703)
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:656)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.<init>(DefaultTestContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Why? What could be the problem? How can I try to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `LoggingBeanPostProcessor` method needs the `@Bean` annotation, not sure if that will solve the issue though

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that the exercise says [*inner* class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3). That is an error. What it actually means is a [*nested* `static` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1).

Declare your `TestInfrastructureConfig` class as `static` within the `RewardNetworkTests` class.

This is further described in the documentation, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management). However, they still use the term *inner class* incorrectly. The JLS describes an *inner class* specifically as a non-`static` nested class. While reading the documentation, you should emphasize the `static`.